# How to deploy django channels 2.x on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-channels, channel

[This tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-django-channels-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-716fd5a49c4a) covers channels 1.x's deployment. However, this does not work with channels 2.x. The failing part is the daemon script, which is as follows:

```
files:"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_daemon.sh":
mode: "000755"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  # Get django environment variables
  djangoenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env 
  | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/%/%%/g' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' 
  | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
  djangoenv=${djangoenv%?}

  # Create daemon configuraiton script
  daemonconf="[program:daphne]
  ; Set full path to channels program if using virtualenv
  command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 <your_project>.asgi:channel_layer
  directory=/opt/python/current/app
  user=ec2-user
  numprocs=1
  stdout_logfile=/var/log/stdout_daphne.log
  stderr_logfile=/var/log/stderr_daphne.log
  autostart=true
  autorestart=true
  startsecs=10

  ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
  ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
  stopwaitsecs = 600

  ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
  ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
  ; taking care of its children as well.
  killasgroup=true

  ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
  ; so it starts first
  priority=998

  environment=$djangoenv

  [program:worker]
  ; Set full path to program if using virtualenv
  command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python manage.py runworker
  directory=/opt/python/current/app
  user=ec2-user
  numprocs=1
  stdout_logfile=/var/log/stdout_worker.log
  stderr_logfile=/var/log/stderr_worker.log
  autostart=true
  autorestart=true
  startsecs=10

  ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
  ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
  stopwaitsecs = 600

  ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
  ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
  ; taking care of its children as well.
  killasgroup=true

  ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
  ; so it starts first
  priority=998

  environment=$djangoenv"

  # Create the supervisord conf script
  echo "$daemonconf" | sudo tee /opt/python/etc/daemon.conf

  # Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
  if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      then
      echo "[include]" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      echo "files: daemon.conf" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  fi

  # Reread the supervisord config
  sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

  # Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
  sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update 

  # Start/Restart processes through supervisord
  sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart daphne
  sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart worker
```

After deployment, AWS has 2 errors in logs: daphne: No such process and worker: No such process.

How should this script be changed, so that it runs on channels 2.x as well?

Thanks

Comment: channels 2 doesnt need daphne

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the reason for mine was the supervisor process that runs these additional scripts wasn't picking up the Daphne process because of this line of code:

`if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf`

This checks if the supervisord.conf file has `[include]` present and adds the daemon process ONLY if there is no `[include]`.

In my case I had a

```
[include]
celery.conf
```

in my supervisord file that prevented this Daphne script from adding the daemon.conf.

There are a few  things you can do:

1. If you have another script creating a .conf file, combine these into one using the same include logic
2. Rewrite the include logic to check for daemon.conf specifically
3. Manually add daemon.conf to the supervisord.conf by SSH into your EC2 instance